# New line in csv cell (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, activerecord, hash

I'd like multiple pieces of data on different lines within the same CSV cell like this:

"String" 2-15-2021 05:26pm

"String ..."

"String..."

I have tried the following and ended up with \n in the cell and not an actual new line, like this "2-15-2021 05:26pm \nHi, it's ...".

`["\n", time, text.body].join("\n")`

`[time, text.body, "\n"].join("\n")`

`[time, text.body].join("\n")`

The input data is an array of hashes. The output of a row is a hash with keys and values, one of the values is a list of strings (or this can be a list of lists of string, I am playing with what I can get to work). The list of strings is where I am trying to add line breaks.

I am using this to create the csv:

```
CSV.open("data.csv", "wb") do |csv|
    csv << list.first.keys
    list.each do |hash|
      csv << hash.values
    end
end
```

Comment: Provide input data (how the `list` looks like) and expected output.

Comment: @stolarz Updated above. The input data is an array of hashes. The output for a row is a hash with keys and values, one of the values is a list of strings. The list of strings is where I am trying to add line breaks to make it readable in a CSV

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing a list of strings that I could then join and add new lines onto.

```
values = []
values.push("#{time}, #{text.body}")

# And then in the hash for the csv, setting the value for that column like this:
{ message: values.join("\n\n")}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for I believe the same answer and with this being the top Google result, this was the eventual answer that I came to that is both brilliant but incredibly simple.

Add an extra `\` to the `\n`.

Essentially anytime you're adding a `\n` to the row it will add that into the output file as a newline and it will break the CSV format. By changing that to `\\n` it will escape the `\` in the `\n` allowing it to be inserted into the CSV field as text rather than a newline.